# Determine remainder of the product of two numbers, when we know the remainder of each individually?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

I want to confirm some of my logic with remainders.  If I know the remainder of $\frac{x}{y}$ is $n$, and the remainder of $
\frac{z}{y}$ is $m$, then can I say that the remainder of $
\frac{xz}{y}$ is $n*m$?

I don't have a formal proof, but I can't find a counter-example.

Comment: You can’t just say it is $nm$, because this may be equal to or larger than $y$. For example, the remainder of dividing $5$ by $3$ is $2$, and the remainder of dividing $11$ by $3$ is $2$, but the remainder of dividing $55$ by $3$ is not $4$.

Comment: Not quite: it is only the remainder of $nm$ modulo $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $x = qy+n$ and $z=ky+m$ for integers $q$ and $k$. So $xz = (qky+qm+nk)y+nm$. So...(spoiler alert: $nm$ might not necessarily be smaller than $y$).

Comment: It's not $qky + qm+ nk$ that you need to worry about...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Oops, my bad...